# Sum resultado de Count, é possível?

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso somar o resultado de um `count()` numa tabela e a função `sum()` não funciona para resultados obtidos com `count()`.

Isso está dentro de um foreach:

```
$occurrence->people_involved->where('tipo_de_envolvimento','VÍTIMA')->count()
```

O resultado é um número pra cada item do loop.

Preciso somar esse resultado, fora do `foreach`, claro.
Como fazer?

Comment: Não entendi precisa explicar melhor

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar uma variável acumuladora:

```
$contador = 0;

foreach(...){
   $count = $occurrence->people_involved->where('tipo_de_envolvimento','VÍTIMA')->count();
   $contador = $contador + $count;
}


dd($contador);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se a resposta a seguir te convém, já que não estou 100% certo de que entendi o que você precisa, mas você poderia alimentar um array com os resultados dos `count()` dentro do seu `foreach()` e posteriormente efetuar as somas que desejar.

Exemplo:

```
$counts = array();

/*isso aqui seria seu foreach()*/

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){ 

   /*aqui você substitui o rand() pelo seu count() e alimenta o array*/
   $counts[] = rand(0, 150);

}
/*agora é só correr o array preenchido, fazendo as somas que você quiser.*/
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer coisa comenta ai que eu tento dar mais alguma dica. Abraços.